# Installing ubuntu 20.04 with dell inspiron dt5410 gives blank screen

Tags: boot, software-installation

As soon as i press install, i get blank screen.Tried also with ubuntu 22.04 but same result

Comment: Do not use 20.04, but 22.04 should work. I have Dell 5310 which is also 11th Gen Intel. I forgot the make the normal UEFI settings changes, even those I normally tell others to change and may appliy with 20.04 or older Dell systems, so RAID & Secure Boot were on. I did have to turn bitlocker & fast start up off in Windows. And it installed without issue. It used an Intel® VMD which I later learned has been in Kernel, but Ubuntu must not have included it in older versions. Do shrink Windows NTFS partiiton with Windows tools first & reboot Windows so it can run chkdsk.

Comment: Hi Oldfred! i did try 22.04 but with same result. haven't tried bitlocker off so i guess i will start from there. Just additional info, i am using 12th gen and nvidia geforce mx550. ill update you on the result. thank you. -edward

Comment: If nVidia, you also need Safe Boot and choose to install optional restricted drivers so nVidia installed as part of install. Otherwise you have to go into grub and use nomodeset and manually install driver from Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Hi oldfred, sorry for newbie questions. I followed your suggestion and now i get a blank screen with cursor in upper left corner. Os still not installed at this point. i get this blank screen with cursor as soon as i click install.

Comment: I tried adding nomodeset before quiet splash and hit ctrl+x. Now i get stuck in Booting a command list.

Comment: Hi oldfred, Just an update. I manage to install the ubuntu 22.10 and it is working now. Older version doesnt work so it seems specs incompatibility. thank you for you patience with me.

Comment: Hi all, apparently 22.10 is not compatible with a program that i MUST install. Actually i am installing ubuntu for this sole purpose. Anymore tips that wasnt mentioned above will be greatly appreciated. i badly need to install 22.04. Thank you

Comment: Start a new question with specifics on program. Is program available as a snap or flatpak? Most programs are not that specific to version, otherwise they should be regularly updated.

Comment: Hi oldfred, i am actually trying to install caldera software for our printer machine and it only runs on specific versions of linux (22.04 for ubuntu).i am able to install 22.10 but once i install caldera, it will notify me that my version of ubuntu is not supported. i tried every suggestion i can find in forums for linux but no luck. First time I install on a dell pc monitor (might be the cause).

Comment: In a couple of weeks 22.04 will get an update to 22.04.2. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/01/ubuntu-22-04-2-point-release-delay You might wait for that.